# How to customize the interface of kibana

Tags: javascript, html, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm working on kibana, and I want to change the interface that kibana is providing. I wanted to change logs, colors and all other options to my own. I have searched around and no one has discussed this. I tried to edit the html files in the folder but there are too many files and I don't know which one is to be edited on my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no officially supported way to do this. It is discussed on their forums [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/changing-kibana-colors/80122/4) and there's a long standing issue for it on [their github](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/9243) (specifically for dashboards).

[This thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/replace-the-kibana-logo/27547/8) discusses changing the logo only, though it is still unsupported. (You change the logo file itself, which changes between versions so will break).